# How to iterate excel sheet cell values with a specific given range in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, excel, c#-4.0

I have tried the below code but it returns only the first row cell values and the script does not return any cell values starting from second row onwards..

The specific range I'm using here is `"BE1:BS1"`. So basically I would need all the cell values that comes under this range.

```cs
xl.Worksheet worksheet = null;
worksheet = workbook.Worksheets[sheetValue] as xl.Worksheet;
//xl.Range range = worksheet.UsedRange;
xl.Range range = (xl.Range)worksheet.get_Range("BE1:BS1");

foreach(xl.Range row in range.Rows)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < row.Columns.Count; j++)
    {
        str = (string)(range.Cells[1, j + 1] as xl.Range).Value2;
        Report.Info(str.ToString());
    }
}
```

[image: ExcelsheetImage]

Comment: Please see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326569/under-what-circumstances-may-i-add-urgent-or-other-similar-phrases-to-my-quest

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that your range is only 1 row!

```
worksheet.get_Range("BE1:BS1")
```

try worksheet.get_Range("BE1:BS14") to proof it.

Comment: it's still the same It returns the first row only.

Comment: I think you don't change the row:
replace str = (string)(range.Cells[1, j + 1] as xl.Range).Value2;
with str = (string)(row.Cells[1, j + 1] as xl.Range).Value2;

Comment: Any progress with it?